# Shouldn't Greedier mode achievements also unlock Greed mode ones?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+

I was working towards unlocking [Godhead](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Godhead) and got all hard mode completion marks on [The Lost](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/The_Lost) except the one for Greedier mode. I didn't have completed Greed mode with this character either, so I didn't unlocked [Zodiac](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Zodiac).

Upon reaching the last floor and killing Ultra Greed, I unlocked Godhead but not Zodiac. Is this expected behaviour? Do I really need to kill Ultra Greed in "simple" Greed mode too?

For what it's worth, I’m playing on Nintendo Switch. Not sure if this behaviour is shared on other platforms.

Comment: I found a [thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/250900/discussions/0/142261027575982994/) with a similar issue. Not sure if that is authoritative enough to count as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is shared on other platforms. Greed and Greedier modes are considered entirely separate - even though Greedier is essentially the "hard mode" of Greed mode. So do not worry, it is completely normal, to unlock Zodiac you simply need to defeat Greed in standard Greed mode as the Lost once more.